# Load package from SQL Server

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I used following article to execute SSIS package parallel.https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/importing-files-in-parallel-with-ssis. In this article it explained execute a package from a folder location. In my situation I am deploying both packages. I tried following code:

```
 Application app = new Application();
 Package pkg = app.LoadFromSqlServer(dtsxPackage, "localhost",null, null, null);
```

I am getting error

> Cannot find folder "Package name"

Package deployment is as follows.

[image]

Using "ParallelExecusion.dtsx" I am try to execute the "FileSync.dtsx" package. I am setting the package path as "FileSync\TeamR\FileSync.dtsx"

Comment: Why are there spaces/tabs and non-numerical values in the names of the files and directories?

Comment: I Edit the image to hide the real values

Answer (score 0):

The code shown is for loading a package that is stored in the SQL Server database named msdb. It will use the binaries in sys.dtspackages90 or  sys.ssispackages (table names approximate) but that only works for packages developed and deployed under the Package Deployment Model (2005-2008R2) or projects that are explicitly defined as such for SQL Server 2012+

What your screenshot shows is a Project Deployment Model which is a .ispac deployed to the SSISDB database. While that package is on SQL Server, you do not use the LoadFromSqlServer method. Instead, you're going to use the same-ish methods that the CLR methods in the database use.

1. [CreateSsisServerExecution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.application.createssisserverexecution?view=sqlserver-2019)
2. [Set any Parameter/Property values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.wrapper.idtsserverexecution100?view=sqlserver-2019)
3. [Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.wrapper.idtsserverexecution100.start?view=sqlserver-2019#Microsoft_SqlServer_Dts_Runtime_Wrapper_IDTSServerExecution100_Start)

Personally, unless I had a strong use case that I needed to control every aspect of the package execution, I'd just use TSQL here (and remove class dependencies in your code) to [Execute SSIS Packages](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2016/11/28/a-better-way-to-execute-ssis-packages-with-t-sql/)